# How to retrieve all matching records

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, `Student`, `Subject` and `Enrollment`. Sample data in all 3 tables is as follows

```
ID Name
1 John
2 Matt
3 Smith

ID Name
1 Maths
2 English
3 Science

StId SubId
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
2     2
3     3
```

From the above tables it is clear that John is mapped to all 3 subjects, Matt is mapped to 2 subjects and Smith is mapped to only 1 subject. Now, how should i write a generic query to get the details of students who are mapped to all subjects? remember that the student and subject count may increase in future.

Comment: How do YOU think you should write it?

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to build a correlated subquery where you get a list of subjects that the student in question hasn't taken

```
DECLARE @N TABLE(NID INT, NName varchar(10))
DECLARE @C TABLE(CID INT, CName varchar(10))
DECLARE @E TABLE(NID INT, CID INT)
INSERT INTO @N VALUES(1,'John'),(2 ,'Matt'),(3,'Smith')
INSERT INTO @C VALUES(1,'Math'),(2 ,'English'),(3,'Science')
INSERT INTO @E VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(3,3)

SELECT * 
FROM @N as N 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM @C as C 
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                    FROM @E as E 
                                    WHERE E.NID = N.NID 
                                        and E.CID = C.CID ))
```

EDIT: BTW, this breaks down if you allows NULLs.

Also, this is easiest to understand if you look from the inside out. At the deepest nesting you are getting a list of "enrollments" for a given Name taking a given Course. A layer out, you are looking for courses for which there is no such enrollment. A layer out from that, you are looking for a student who doesn't have such a course. So your query becomes "Find the details of all students who don't have a course that exists but the student didn't take"

And thanks Bluefeet, that formatting does look nicer :-)